# XMLHttpRequest, readyState issue

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In a web page, I am using *XMLHttpRequest*.
And I am having trouble, because things don't happen as usual.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Here useful work is done.
      .......
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET","readUser.php?EL="+user.email,true);
  xmlHttp.send();
```

But lately for some reason, this is happening:

```
this.status == 200 (as expected)
```

but:

```
this.readyState == 3 (and not 4 as usual)
```

As a result, the "useful work" is not done.

How can I get "this.readyState" back to 4 ?

Or how can I find why "this.readyState" is not 4 as it should ?

My experience using XMLHttpRequest is rather limited, so I am kind of lost when things go wrong like here. Beside when I run "readUser.php?EL=somemail@example.com" aside (independently). There is no problem and I don't see any issue.

I have tried with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, getting the same behaviour; so I presume it is not a browser related issue.

++++++
For reference, readUser is a PHP page, here is the relevant code in readUser.php

```
<?php
....
ConnectToDB();

$query = 'SELECT * FROM MyDBTable';
$query .= sprintf(" WHERE MlAdr='%s'",$_GET['EL']);
$DBS=$Connection->query($query);
$DBS->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dataJSON = json_encode($DBS->fetch());
echo $dataJSON;
?>
```

Comment: By following the suggestion in your link I can display the length of the response, but it doesn't tell me why it doesn't go further.

Comment: As a matter of fact the length is the expected length. So I wonder why the readyState does not go to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` use

```
xmlHttp.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    // Here useful work is done.
    .......
  }
}
```

The xhr (XMLHttpRequest) approach is oldscool - consider to use more modern approach: [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: I just tried "xmlHttp.onload = function()". It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that readUser.php finished response (send all data and closed connection).

Comment: Indeed I don't think I close the connection an never did that. I just query the DB to get what I want and echo it. How should I close the connection?

Comment: Try two headers:
Connection: close
Content-Length: n (n = size of output in bytes )

Comment: I am not sure so get the meaning of your comment, so I added the code for readUser in the post. It will be easier for you to let me know what you mean.

Comment: Looks good, but check with any tool that response is finished. I am not sure about php, but node.js can leave connection opened, and "echo" something after a minute, so load event can never fire. May be you are using some tool or something that can print into opened connection without closing it. For better test, please provide test server URL with the same problem.

Comment: Or try just "echo 123" to see if something changes.

Comment: The only thing I can say, this used to work the way it is.